# Very low speed rates on home network via Samba

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, samba

Today I installed OpenELEC which came with Samba server by default. I wanted to send a movie from my PC and got really low speed rates - around 300kbps. I have TP-LINK TD-W8960N router. The server computer connects to it wirelessly using TP-LINK TL-WN821N and the client computer connects to it using ethernet cable. With this setup I should get speed rate around 300mbps, while I get 300**k**bps...

Any idea what could be the problem?

Here's my another question which might be somehow related to this: [NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT error while sending a file to Samba server](https://superuser.com/questions/726390/nt-status-io-timeout-error-while-sending-a-file-to-samba-server)

Comment: I think you're confusing bytes with bits and true data rates with peak line speeds. 802.11n has a theoretical peak line speed of 300 million bits per second, while you are measuring a true data rate of 300 kilobytes per second. Also, the wired ports on your TD-W8960N top out at 100Mbps. Since there are 8 bits in a byte, 1,024 bytes in a kilobyte and 1,024 kilbytes in a megabyte, that gives us a theoretical maximum of 11.9MB/s.

Comment: Welp, it's still faster than 300k{B,b}ps.