# NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT error while sending a file to Samba server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, samba

Today I installed OpenELEC which came with Samba server by default. When I try to send a file using smbclient on linux I get it sending for a moment, but then it stops and I get error

```
cli_push returned NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT closing remote file \example.txt
```

I have TP-LINK TD-W8960N router. The server computer connects to it wirelessly using TP-LINK TL-WN821N and the client computer connects to it using ethernet cable. Any idea?

Here's my another question which might be somehow related to this: [Very low speed rates on home network via Samba](https://superuser.com/questions/726369/very-low-speed-rates-on-home-network-via-samba)

Comment: Almost three years later, I have this problem, too.  I've seen that other information on the internet suggested adding the smb server's ip to the /etc/hosts file, but that didn't fix my issue.  Files will partially transfer and then stop and seem to fail at certain specific file sizes on the smb share.

Answer (score 2):

Try just to add a timeout option
`-t <timeout in seconds>`; for example, `-t 3600`.